# Is it possible to recompile for AMD an app which has been developed on a Mac M1?

Tags: macos, webview, cross-compiling

I have developed an app using Go and Webview (Webview bindings for Go).

https://github.com/webview/webview

When I attempt to recompile it (cross-compile it) for an AMD architecture (using the relevant Go compiler switches), it doesn’t work because the Webview bindings are in fact a library which is architecture-dependant.

Is there a way around this (use an old Mac or an emulator or a special terminal) ?

Comment: Did you recompile webview?

Answer (score 0):

The following command does the trick (the option `CGO_ENABLED=1` is needed to recompile the dependencies upon Webview):

```
mkdir -p ${APP}.app/Contents/MacOS
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -o ${APP}.app/Contents/MacOS/${APP}
```